# Why is a parameter's private field visible to a generic method in Java 6 but not in Java 7?

Tags: java, generics, java-7, private-members, generic-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type-parameterized field of a generic class becomes invisible after upgrading to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719843/type-parameterized-field-of-a-generic-class-becomes-invisible-after-upgrading-to)

```
public class Test{

    private String _canYouSeeMe = "yes";

    <T extends Test> void genericMethod(T hey){
        String s = hey._canYouSeeMe;
    }

    void method(Test hey){
        String s = hey._canYouSeeMe;
    }   
}
```

When building against JDK 1.6 this compiles just fine but against 1.7 there is a compiler error in genericMethod():
The field Test._canYouSeeMe is not visible

The error can be resolved by making _canYouSeeMe protected rather than private, but I'm just wondering what has changed from 1.6 to 1.7

Comment: why not? this is a method of the same class, isn't it? and non-static, too.

Comment: @fmucar Compiled fine here with openjdk 1.6.0_24.

Comment: error, and just in 1.7. It compiles and just fine in 1.6 so is it a resolved bug or is just that 1.7 is more strict?

Comment: It makes sense that it does not compile: T could be a subclass of Test, which would not have access to a private member of Test.

Comment: @fmucar No, it _shouldn't_ have compiled, you were right with that. It did, however.

Comment: @assylias: actually, it doesn't make a lot of sense: If `T` is a subclass of `Test` then it's also a `Test` and we should be able to access `Test._canYouSeeMe`. Actually: casting `hey` to `Test` makes it work in Java 7.

Comment: BTW, what if I explicitly cast T to Test and *then* try to access the private field?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7719843

Comment: For simplicities sake you can reduce the problem to using a subclass of `Test` as the argument type and avoid generics.

Comment: Yes, very interesting finding. Now I wonder why as well but i still think that it should not compile on 1.6 as well although it compiles

Comment: @MicSim: great find, that's indeed the reason. And a very interesting change as well!

Comment: @JoachimSauer See my non answer ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclasses (`T)` of a class (`Test`) *never* have access to the superclass' private fields. This was likely a bug in the Java 6 compiler that was fixed in Java 7.

Remember: `T extends Test` means that `T` is a subclass of `Test`. It does *not* mean that `T`'s class is `Test.class`, which is the necessary condition for having private field & method access.

Comment: this is partly true, but since the code accessing the private field is in the superclass itself, I would say it should have the access

Comment: @Matt: I don't get it. If that were true, then why does casting `hey` to `Test` (which is entirely legitimate and doesn't even produce a warning) let's us access `_canYouSeeMe`?

Comment: +1 A number of bugs in Java 6 were not fixed until Java 7 to avoid causing an incompatibility.

Comment: Matt, so even though it's a static method (that uses generics), the compiler treats that as a generic class itself?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Because adding a field named `_canYouSeeMe` to the given subtype of `Test` would change the field access expression to refer to the new field. In this case, where the given type is a type variable, lowering the upper bound on the type variable could similarly change the meaning. Those bugs would creep up on us in utter silence. I for one welcome that particular door being firmly shut.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to @Joachim - too long for a comment.

It is consistent with the fact that this would not compile:

```
void method(SubTest hey) {
    String s = hey._canYouSeeMe;
}
```

(where SubTest extends Test) whereas this would compile

```
void method(SubTest hey) {
    String s = ((Test) hey)._canYouSeeMe;
}
```

Comment: The second example does not compile (in both Java 6 & 7) when `SubTest` is a top-level class.

Comment: @MattBall: why not? as long as `SubTest` extends `Test`. It compiles for me.

Comment: @MattBall if `method` is a member of Test, it does compile, even if `SubTest` is a top level class.

Comment: @assylias yes, it compiles [iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff) `method` is a member of `Test`.

Comment: @MattBall Yes - you can't access a private member of Test outside of Test (or its top level enclosing class if it is not a top level class itself).